# Squeelize unable to access foreign key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying this example:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'foo/database.sqlite'
});

class User extends Sequelize.Model {
}

User.init({
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'user'
});

class Project extends Sequelize.Model {
}

Project.init({
    name: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'project'
});

User.hasMany(Project);
User.create({
    name: "foo",
    tags: [
        {name: "project_1"}
    ]
}, {
    include: [Project]
});

Project.sync().then(() => console.log("project table created"));
User.sync().then(() => console.log("user table created"));

User.findAll().then((users) => {
    for (user of users) {
        console.log(user.Projects);

    }
});
```

For a given user, I was hoping to get all projects. However, this prints out undefined.

How do I access the project of a given user?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to specify in your selection that you want the projects too:

```
User.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Project
    }]
})
```

Comment: I tried out your suggestion and it works. I don't quite understand...so, in my example, I added a project for a user. However,  this was done through tags, so it doesn't have an id. This is all very confusing...

Comment: I'm new-ish to sequelize as well. hasMany should have added a foreign key field. I'm not sure how the tag is stored, but the include bit has worked for me so far.

Comment: yeah, I'm very confused. I was expecting to get one project printed out when running this snippet, but nothing got printed out. https://ideone.com/ovKaYM